# Split multiple columns based on condition and rename

Tags: r, split, rename, multiple-columns

I have a large dataset (1Gb) that looks like this:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3
ID1      1:2=2.3  2:3=7
ID2      1:2=3.2  2:3=8
ID3      1:2=6.5  2:3=10
```

From this, I would like to create a new dataset:

```
Column1  1:2  2:3
ID1      2.3  7
ID2      3.2  8
ID3      6.5  0
```

Basically, I need to separate the dataframe based on "=", get rid of the new columns, keep only the values and re-naming the columns with 1:2, 2:3 (without having to use the colnames function as I have hundreds of columns).

I am considering creating a loop or a function, which would split the columns using `str_split_fixed` and merge the desired columns together into a new dataframe.

I am thinking there should be an easier way.
Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it,

```
nms <- sapply(df[-1], function(i)unique(sub('=.*', '', i)))
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(i)sub('.*=', '', i))
names(df)[-1] <- nms
df
#  Column1 1:2 2:3
#1     ID1 2.3   7
#2     ID2 3.2   8
#3     ID3 6.5   9
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(Column1 = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3"), Column2 = c("1:2=2.3", 
"1:2=3.2", "1:2=6.5"), Column3 = c("2:3=7", "2:3=8", "2:3=9")), .Names = c("Column1", 
"Column2", "Column3"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = data.frame(Column1=c("ID1","ID2","ID3"), Column2=c("A:B=2.3","A:B=3.2","A:B=6.5"), Column3 =c("D:E=7","D:E=8","D:E=9"))
new = data.frame(df$Column1, apply(df[,c("Column2","Column3")], 2, function(x) str_extract(x, "\\d+\\.*\\d*")))
colnames(new) = c("Column1", "Column2", "Column3")
```

Comment: Also, I have over 200 columns with the format A:B, C:D...etc. What if I want to extract the actual "A:B", "C:D" and add it as colnames without having to type it "by hand"?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. It gets a bit more tricky if we have "1:2" and "2:3" instead of "A:B" and "D:E"

Comment: Edited. So basically the idea is to take Columns and extract only digit followed by "." followed by another digit. Regex do the magic.

Comment: Thanks but it does not seem to work with the format "1:2", "2:3". Instead, I do the following but I still struggle to extract "1:2", "2:3" and add them as colnames without having to type it by hand with the colnames function: new = data.frame(df$Column1, apply(df[,c("Column2","Column3")], 2, function(x) gsub("\\d:\\d=","\\1", x)))

Comment: data.frame(df$Column1, apply(df[,c("Column2","Column3")], 2, function(x) str_extract(x, "\\d+\\:*\\d*"))) this one grabs only 1:2, 2:3 etc

Comment: Thanks! Although I am not looking to create a new data frame with 1:2, 2:3...etc but to use 1:2, 2:3 as column names. My question might not be super clear.